# Glassfish Node Clustering

Tags: glassfish-3

Excuse Me sir , I have a research project to clustering glassfish3 on different server.
My simple implementation is :

When u have 2 Glassfish servers on different server , called Server A and Server B.

When glassfish on Server A suddenly off or down , it will do 'failover' to Glassfish on Server B , and session doesnt loss or change ?

I have tried for glassfish session clustering from link [JavaDUDE](http://javadude.wordpress.com/2011/05/12/glassfish-3-1-%E2%80%93-clustering-tutorial-part2-sessions/).
But it just works on 1 instance of glassfish server , any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a webapp for testing the failover? If so, have you made it distributable? (Check: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2426/abdle.html#scrolltoc for details)